# how would i go about allowing me to change the tag of an object on runtime with OnCollisionEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    while (onWeapon == false && collision.gameObject.tag == "Weapon")
    {
        onWeapon = true;
    } 
    
    
    
    if (onWeapon == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        currentPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        collision.transform.position = currentPos;
        collision.transform.parent = player.transform;
        collision.tag = "WeaponHeld";
    }

    
}
```

i cant change the object tag on runtime with "OnEnterCollision2D" but the same line worked when i used "OnTriggerEnter2D"

Comment: Did you define "WeaponHeld" tag at unity editor?

Comment: Yea WeaponHeld is already a tag in the editor,that isnt the problem, the "tag" in collision.tag itself

Comment: ohh I see, because collision2d does not inherit from component, so you can not access directly to tag. but you can access the transform. Then you can accees the tag from transform like that. collision.transform.tag = "WeaponHeld";

Comment: When you try to change the tag of the game object instead of directly do it in the collision, it still no working?

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is your `while` loop good for? Anyway there will be only exactly one single iteration so just make it

```
if(!onWeapon && collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon"))
{
    onWeapon = true;
}
```

Then a [`Collision2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) is a data container **struct** with specific data about the collision and itself has no tag.

The [`gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-gameObject.html) you collide with has

```
collision.gameObject.tag = "WeaponHeld";
```

Or since you are using the [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-transform.html) anyway you can also use that one

```
var otherTransform = collision.transform;
otherTransform.position = currentPos;
otherTransform.parent = player.transform;
otherTransform.tag = "WeaponHeld";
```

because it has the property [`tag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-tag.html) as well which forwards to the according `gameObject.tag`.

---

> Why did it work in [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)?

Because there as a parameter you don't get a [`Collision2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) struct but rather a [`Collider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) component reference.

And as just mentioned also for `Transform` the base class [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) **has** the property [`tag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-tag.html) which basically simply forwards to the according `gameObject.tag` (see [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Component.bindings.cs#L173)).